# JPA : why closing Session after a transaction commit?

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, jpa, transactions

In the following application example, i use JPA, @Transactional spring annotation and jta for transaction.

If I understand correctly the session-per-request-with-detached-object :

- a http request is coming
- a method #1 annotated @Transactional is executed : Session is open with openSession() and bind to jta context, a transaction is opened
- the method is finished, and also the transaction : Session is closed, persistence context is cleared.
- a call to several web services are done
- a method #2 annotated @Transactionnal is executed : Session is obtained with getCurrentSession(), and a new transaction is opened. I have to reattach all the modified data in the Session if I want to save them.

So my question is : why we don't let the Session opened after the end of the first transaction. So in the second transaction we would not have te merge objects : it can save some 'select' queries to the database.

??